# Getting Salesforce Object Id

Tags: api, custom-object, tooling-api

Is it possible to use the Salesforce API to get an object's internal salesforce id. For example this id appears in the URL for a custom object setup:
https://cs15.salesforce.com/ID?setupid=CustomObjects

*Update;* I used the tooling API with this query to get the object DeveloperName + the internal SF Id:

```
/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+DeveloperName,+ExternalName+from+CustomObject
```

Answer (score 2):

The [listMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm) call in the Metadata API provides this functionality. I'm not aware of any other API calls that provide this ID value.

Comment: I was actually able to use the REST tooling API with this query:            /services/data/v33.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id,DeveloperName,ExternalName+FROM+CustomObject